# MAX11609 - Crosstalk in Voltage Inputs

Tags: arduino, adc, crosstalk

So I designed a module which can read multiple voltage and current(4-20mA) inputs. This module has been designed with the use of Max11609. After receiving the PCBs and testing them, I observed a strange thing. When I supply a voltage to any channel, the other channels also display some values in Arduino serial monitor. The schematic and layout of the chip is given below;

[image]

[image]

So when I provide voltage input to channel VIN1, the below digital readings are observed:

VIN1 -> 767

VIN2 -> 460

VIN3 -> 135

VIN4 -> 0

Now VIN1 is absolutely correct and shows the digital value corresponding to voltage supplied. But why are other channels showing such erratic behaviour ? Is it because of cross talk or could it be because of the sampling interval between subsequent channels ?

**PS:** I am using [this](https://github.com/AllAboutEE/MAX11609EEE-Breakout-Board/blob/master/Software/Arduino/AllAboutEE-MAX11609-Library/AllAboutEE_MAX11609.cpp) code.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Are the other channels connected to something, or floating?

Comment: @Mattman944 : Presently they are not connected to anything.

Comment: The inputs are very high impedance and will easily pickup other nearby signals. So, you could say it is crosstalk, but it is expected in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did a bit of research on this and found that there are  a couple of solutions : 1. GNDing the unused pins so that they are not floating 2. using op amp between signal and ADC. Will try that in the next revision of this board.